# Colored cells in a table and multicol

Tags: tables, color, multicol

Is it be relatively easy to create a table with colored cells, many columns on a particular row and text centered in each box to produce the following output [image]

I'm having trouble understanding how to create tables, having read various tutorials I cannot seem to produce a table like the one above. I'd be grateful of any help constructing the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to Sebastiano answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mcsix}[1]{\multicolumn{6}{l|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{blue!45}}l | *{6}{l|}}
\hline
text    &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
proof   & \mcsix{}              \\ \hline
begin   & \mcsix{}              \\ \hline
gray    & \mcsix{}              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For coloring of one column is sufficient to define for example `>{\columncolor{blue!45}}l`. `cellcolor` is dedicated for coloring particular cell, however use `>{\cellcolor{blue!45}}l` gives the same result as above MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much for cite of my name. With you and the other users here I am learning new commands. Thanks again and Merry Christmas to you and your family.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are welcome! And Merry Christmas and Happy and Prosper New Year to you and your family! Happy TeX-ing!

Answer (score 4):

In ConTeXt MKIV you can use Natural Tables for the job.

```
\starttext

\setupTABLE[option=stretch]
\setupTABLE[each][each][align=middle]
\setupTABLE[column][first][background=color,backgroundcolor=cyan]
\startTABLE
  \NC TEXT \NC \NC \NC \NC \NC \NC \NC\NR
  \NC TEXT \NC[nx=6] \NC\NR
  \NC TEXT \NC[nx=6] \NC\NR
  \NC TEXT \NC[nx=6] \NC\NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. My compliments.

Answer (score 3):

I hope to help you. Sincerely my source is very simple and poor.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hhh]
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0cm}
\caption{My table}
\begin{tabular}{|
>{\cellcolor{blue!45}}l |l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!45} text &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
\cellcolor{blue!45} proof & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\cellcolor{blue!45} begin & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\cellcolor{blue!45} gray & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the`\columncolor` command, from `colortbl` (loaded by the `[table]` option of `xcolor`). I added some padding to the cells, changing the value of `\arraystretch`.

*Added:* A second solution, with `tabularx` can fill the whole line width.    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array,  tabularx, caption}%
     \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
  \caption{My table}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\bfseries\columncolor{RoyalBlue!80}}m{2cm} |*{8}{m{3mm}|}}
    \hline
    TEXT &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
    TEXT & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} \\ \hline
    TEXT & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} \\ \hline
    TEXT & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
  \caption{My table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\bfseries\columncolor{RoyalBlue!80}\hsize =3\hsize}X |*{8}{ >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X|}}
    \hline
    TEXT &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
    TEXT & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} \\ \hline
    TEXT & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} \\ \hline
    TEXT & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{} \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way of stretching the table so that it is textwidth?